# Веб доступ к десктопному приложению

Tags: c++, веб-программирование

Объясню суть проблемы: 
есть десктопное графическое приложение ,написанное на с++, появилась **срочная** необходимость доступа к нему через web браузер, а именно чтобы сервер, при обращении к нему, поднимал на своей стороне эту программу и достаточно того чтобы он каким-либо способом передавал на сторону клиента вывод самого приложения.

Платформа: windows;
графический API: OpenGL | GLFW;

Была мысль того, чтобы переписать часть кода, отвечающую за отрисовку, так чтобы картинка непосредственно преобразовывалась в поток байт, который затем и будет пересылаться клиенту, но способ весьма время-затратный, существуют ли другие возможности для реализации этой "фичи"?

(Времени переписать код на другой язык попросту нет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поднимаете VNC сервер, потом поднимаете сервер noVNC, который транслирует протокол VNC в HTML5. Собственно, на этом вопрос "показать десктопное приложение на вебе" заканчивается.

Дальше начинаются частные вопросы - вопрос с качеством и отзывчивостью картинки, вопрос с авторизацией пользователей, вопрос с запуском этого дела на каком-то сервере.

Первое решается использованием видеокарты с аппаратной поддержкой сжатия видео - и венда, и линукс позволяют рисовать из OpenGL прямо в буфер компрессора на видеокарте, и снимать с видеокарты уже поток сжатого видео.

Второе зависит от политики предоставляемого сервиса.

Третий вопрос таки уже сильно зависит от используемой ОС и серверной платформы.

Answer (score 4):

Это конечно не панацея, однако, Взгляните на [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/)

Цитата из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten)

> Целью развития проекта Emscripten является создание инструмента,
> который позволил бы выполнять в Интернете код независимо от языка
> программирования, на котором этот код написан.
>
> Emscripten позволяет
> осуществить компиляцию байткода LLVM в код на языке JavaScript,
> который может быть выполнен внутри веб-браузера. Байткод LLVM может быть сгенерирован с
> исходных текстов C / C ++ с помощью компиляторов llvm-gcc и clang, а
> также из кода на другом языке программирования, для которого
> существует LLVM-фронтенд.
>
> Emscripten поддерживает трансляцию вывода
> библиотеки SDL через canvas, а также оказывает поддержку OpenGL через
> WebGL.

---

Вот примеры, доступные в сети:

[DOOM3](http://wasm.continuation-labs.com/d3demo/)

[Broadway.js](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway) - H264 кодек

https://homepages.loria.fr/BLevy/GEOGRAM/vorpaview.html

https://homepages.loria.fr/BLevy/GEOGRAM/geogram_demo_Delaunay2d.html

Comment: В таком случае, приложение придется "подарить" клиенту. Если это уместно, то ок.

Comment: И нужно будет провести работы по портированию работы с файловой системой, если она есть.

Comment: @gbg не все продукты для интернета, работа с фс продумана, она сделана поверх `indexeddb` при помощи модуля https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS